# How to avoid two-way data binding in Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I'm building an app in Angular 8 and I have the following problem regarding data-binding.

I have a table with data. I want to edit a specific entry. So, in the **app.component.html**, I have:

```
<table>
   <tr *ngFor="let entry of entries">
      <th>{{ entry.asset }}</th>
      <th>{{ entry.model }}</th>
      <th>{{ entry.ip }}</th>
      <th>
         <a (click)="editIconPressed(entry)"><i class="material-icons">create</i></a>
      </th>
   </tr>
</table>
```

In the **app.component.ts**, I have the corresponding function:

```
editIconPressed(entry: Entry): void {
   this.edittedEntry = entry;
   this.showEditModal = true;   
}
```

With the variable `showEditModal`, a modal is opened in order the selected entry to be editted. The code for the modal is inside the same file, **app.component.html**.

```
<div class="modal" [style.display]="showEditModal ? 'block' : 'none'">
   <div class="modal-content edit-entry-modal-width">
      <form #editEntryForm="ngForm">
         <input class="edit-entry-form-input-field" type="text" [(ngModel)]="edittedEntry.asset" name="model">
         <input class="edit-entry-form-input-field" type="text" [(ngModel)]="edittedEntry.model" name="serial">
         <input class="edit-entry-form-input-field" type="text" [(ngModel)]="edittedEntry.ip" name="serial">
         <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" (click)="editEntrySaveBtnPressed()">Save</button>      
      </form>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="closeModal()">Cancel</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

So, the user can edit the form and automatically, because of the two-way data-binding, the table entry behind the modal will change as well. If the user pushes the "Save" button, `editEntrySaveBtnPressed()` function is called and the database is updated, as well as the table inside the template.

However, if the user pushes the "Cancel" button, the `closeModal()` function is called which is just closing the modal. Unfortunatelly, the change on the table in the template is remaining although the user cancelled the edit.

```
editEntrySaveBtnPressed(): void {  
            this.entryService
                .editEntry(this.edittedEntry)
                .subscribe(res => {
                    this.edittedEntry = { _id: '', asset: '', model: '', ip: '' };
                    this.showSuccessMsgForEdit = true;
                    setTimeout(() => { this.closeModal(); } , 2000);
                }, err => {
                    this.errorMsg = err;
                    this.showErrorMsg = true;
                });
}

closeModal(): void {
        this.edittedEntry = { _id: '', asset: '', model: '', ip: '' };
        this.showEditModal = false;
}
```

Any ideas for the change not being passed on the table inside the template??

Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: Well, create a copy of the entry before edting it. When saving, replace the original entry by the edited copy.

Comment: use  spread operator to get a copy `this.edittedEntry = {...entry};` and a variable 'index`to store the index selected, then in ok, use `entries[index]={...this.edittedEntry}`. Othe aproach is make a copy of old values `this.oldValues={...entry}`, and in cancel use `entries[index]={...this.oldValues}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are sharing the reference between the objects entry and edittedEntry in the below line

```
 this.edittedEntry = entry;
```

hence need to use Object.assign({}, entry} or {...entry} when copying the values of entry to edittedEntry.

When saving use the index to update the values back in to the entry something like,

```
this.entry[selectedIndex] = {...this.edittedEntry}
```

Comment: It works, but I suppose you mean `entries` insteed of `entry`. I editted it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

It happens because you are assigning reference to the `edittedEntry`. This is how reference types works. So just create a brand new object from existing object `entry`.

```
edittedEntry: any;

editIconPressed(entry: Entry): void {
   this.edittedEntry = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(entry));
   this.showEditModal = true;   
}
```